# How to do in-memory search for polygons that contain a given point?

Tags: postgresql, redis, polygon, point-in-polygon, geohashing

I have a PostgreSQL table that has a `geometry` type column, in which different simple polygons (possibly intersecting) are stored. The polygons are are all areas within a city. I receive an input of a point (latitude-longitude pair) and need to find the list of polygons that contain the given point. What I have currently:

- Unclustered GiST index defined on the polygon column.
- Use `ST_Contains(@param_Point, table.Polygon)` on the whole table.

It is quite slow, so I am looking for a more performant in-memory alternative. I have the following ideas:

1. Maintain dictionary of polygons in Redis, keyed by their geohash. Polygons with same geohash would be saved as a list. When I receive the point, calculate its geohash and trim to a desired level. Then search in the Redis map and keep trimming the point's geohash until I find the first result (or enough results).
2. Have a trie of geohashes loaded from the database. Update the trie periodically or by receiving update events. Calculate the point's geohash, search in the trie until I find enough results. I prefer this because the map may have long lists for a geohash, given the nature of the polygons.
3. Any other approaches?

I have read about libraries like [GeoTrie](https://github.com/CptFoobar/geotrie) and [Polygon Geohasher](https://github.com/Bonsanto/polygon-geohasher) but can't seem to integrate them with the database and the above ideas.

Any cues or starting points, please?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same task at hand and thought to maybe use Tile38. Have you looked into Tile38 can it do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ST_Within? Not sure if it meets your criteria but I believe it is meant to be faster than st_contains

Comment: Not yet, but I can try and revert with results. However, an event-based system which maintains the whole polygon data hierarchically in Redis would be ideal.